# Почему не изменяется свободное место при установке ubuntu рядом с windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Устанавлию с флешки ubuntu рядом с десяткой на одном хдд. Свободное место отделил, но дальше оно не изменяется не делится. Слабо в этом разбираюсь

Comment: На MBR-диске не помещается больше четырёх разделов.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно удалить последний раздел, создать на его месте `расширенный`. Далее можно будет создать новый раздел ntfs и добавлять больше 4х разделов.

Без потерь данных думаю это можно сделать каким-то продвинутым менеджером дисков. Можно и руками, но опасно и только с консоли:

уменьшаешь третий раздел на один блок. запоминаешь начало и конец 4ого раздела. удаляешь 4ый. создаешь расширенный. создаешь новый раздел с началом и концом удаленного раздела. на вопрос об удалении файловой системы отвечаешь отрицательно.